# Nginx не редиректит www на nonwww

Tags: nginx

Настраиваю редирект сайта с www на без www кириллического домена. Но при переходе на www.сайт.рф  открывается заглушка nginx. Вот мой конфиг

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name  www.xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai;
       return       301 http://xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name  xn--80acjdwguci9fxb.xn--p1ai;

       access_log    /var/log/nginx/shkolapobedy.access.log;
       error_log     /var/log/nginx/shkolapobedy.error.log;

       root /var/www/blago;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

Comment: А зачем делаешь редирект? Просто добавь через пробел ещё один server_name. Тогда nginx будет слушать запросы и на адрес без www

Comment: Пробовал, тоже заглушка nginx открывается. Поэтому решил редирект, но без результата

Comment: Тогда попробуй посмотреть в сторону настройки проброса у домена. Должна стоять строка хост *, Тип А и Значение твой IP.
Так или иначе перенаправления быть не должно.

Comment: Загадочно. Проверил в DNS обе записи сделаны